# android:enlarging an image on click

Tags: android, imageview

I am making an android app in which i need to enlarge the image size on click.
I am getting these images downloaded from server and then adding these images programmatically in the activity and hence setting id of images programmatically. Now my problem is that when i send the imageid o another activity to enlarge it it is taking only the id of last image.

and hence gives the following exception.

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emx.OnDaMove/com.emx.OnDaMove.FullImageActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x5
```

i am using the following code for making images and adding them to table rows.

```
             imageUrl = "http://ondamove.it/English/images/users/";
            imageUrl = imageUrl + listObject.get(j).getImage();

            image = new ImageView(this);
            image.setPadding(20, 10, 0, 0);
            image.setId(j+1);
            imageId=image.getId();
                            tr.addView(image);
```

and the following method for clickliastener:

```
     private OnClickListener clickImageListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),FullImageActivity.class);
        fullScreenIntent.putExtra(ProfilePageNormalUser.class.getName(),imageId) ;
        ProfilePageNormalUser.this.startActivity(fullScreenIntent); 

    }
};
```

and the activity in which images are to be enlarged is:

```
        ImageView myimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewEnlarged);

    Intent intent = getIntent();


     int imageId = (Integer) intent.getExtras().get(ProfilePageNormalUser.class.getName());
      System.out.println("********"+imageId +"**********");
      InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(imageId);
      Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
      Matrix imageMatrix = new Matrix();
      imageMatrix.postRotate(90);
      Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, myimage.getWidth(), myimage.getHeight(), originalBitmap.getWidth(), originalBitmap.getHeight(), imageMatrix, false);
      myimage.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
      myimage.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya surely it will give the last Id since the value of imageId will be update on every loop. This will store the last known value during looping.

You should use array instead of simple variable.

or you can use v.getId in onClick method. (simpler one)

Comment: even getting the id in onclick method is giving me the same exception

Comment: Can you Log the ID in onClick and see what does it return. If it isn't for the ID than the error should be at InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(imageId);

Comment: Ya its Possible but you need a server that receives and send the text. And also the receiver should have your app for that.